# View markdown files offline

Tags: github, markdown, viewer

Is there a way to display `.md` files offline so we know what it will look like once it's uploaded in Github? I'm referring to showing the `README.md` file as it would come out in Github, and not as for editing purposes.

Needs to work on Mac and Windows since I use both.

Answer (score 323, accepted):

I wrote [Grip](http://github.com/joeyespo/grip) a while ago to do exactly this. It renders **exactly** like it does on GitHub and provides several additional options too:

- In addition to READMEs, Grip can renders GitHub comments and issues
- Click through local links to render other .md files
- An API to use in your own projects
- Export to an HTML file

Install with pip:

```
pip install grip
```

Then go to the directory that contains your README file and run:

```
grip
```

Pass `-h` for additional help and options.

Here's a screenshot of Grip rendering Grip's README:

[image: Screenshot of Grip rendering Grip]

[Check it out here](http://github.com/joeyespo/grip).

Comment: It is in fact really useful, but it does not render exactly like github (e.g. raw html, some syntax highlightning, etc). I found that [gfms](https://github.com/ypocat/gfms) solution (python based) gets the job done pretty well.

Comment: @luchosrock Could you post a gist of Markdown that doesn't render correctly? If there's any mismatch, then I'll file a bug and fix it.

Comment: @luchosrock I think you may be confusing the two though. From gfms's own docs, "the current implementation of GFMS doesn't color the source code blocks", whereas Grip does. Grip uses GitHub's own Markdown API and styles out-of-the-box, not a custom solution, which is what makes Grip so accurate. Also, gfms is *node* based, not Python.

Comment: yeah I must have confused. I never said it was a bad tool anyway. Thanks for writing it.

Comment: Unlike other solutions, works like a charm on Linux! Thanks!

Comment: Note that links in github wikis dont work, ie you link to `[foo](foo)`, and it tries to open page `foo`, but it should open `foo.md`

Comment: This is a useful tool, however it seems to use GitHub's API for actually rendering the page in the browser. When I refresh the page more than 30 times, I get a "GitHub Rate Limit Reached" error. It appears that Grip does not support Offline viewing.

Answer (score 479):

There are a few Chrome plug-ins that work well. I've been using [Markdown Preview Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-preview-plus/febilkbfcbhebfnokafefeacimjdckgl).

After install, enable "Allow access to file URLs" in Extensions (menu > More tools > Extensions or enter URL `chrome://extensions/` instead).

[image]

Then drag-n-drop a Markdown file onto Chrome and use your favorite editor to edit.

Answer (score 117):

[Atom](https://atom.io/) by Github. Gives you a side by side preview.

[image]

Comment: This is nice if you are editing many .md files. And instant preview, without having to toggle to another app is always a plus.

Comment: There's even an auto-scroll package: https://github.com/mark-hahn/markdown-scroll-sync. Currently, you'd have to patch https://github.com/mark-hahn/markdown-scroll-sync/pull/66/files for it work with out warnings.

Comment: This is also a good suggestion as well. Instant preview with side-by-side pane is a bonus! No need to save and tab out constantly.

Comment: in Atom, "Packages -> Markdown Preview -> Toggle Preview" to actually see the rendered document

Comment: Now that `Atom` has been sunset by Microsoft. Can someone recommend an alternative still endorsed by the GitHub team?

Answer (score 93):

**Visual Studio Code** - the new editor by Microsoft also provides very good support for markdown editing.
You can download it from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download).
The editor provides good support to **toggle** between the **markdown code** and the **preview mode**.
It also provides reasonably good **intellisense** support for all the markdown syntax.
The editor is **free for use** and is also **cross platform** (works on Linux, Windows and Mac).
For more details you can check on their [website](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown)

[image]

Comment: Cool, a solution I had installed already! I had two small things to figure out: To open the preview pane, right-click the file's tab along the top and select "Open Preview (Ctrl?Shift+V)". To invoke the intellisense that @sundeep mentions, press Ctrl+Space in the editor window.

Comment: ctrl+k v to preview

Comment: In case somebody's floundering for the macOS combination it's Cmd + Shift + v

Answer (score 63):

Late to the party, but have a look at [MarkdownPad](http://www.markdownpad.com/).

Comment: If you want to get support for github flavoured markdown you'll have to get MarkdownPad Pro - for ~15USD. I personally would pay maybe 5USD for it but for sure not 15USD. So if somebody can recommend something else please do so.

Comment: Just paid the $15 for the pro version, imho worth it, but would be nice if it ran under Mono so I could use it in linux/osx, which is where more of my dev is heading these days.

Comment: MarkdownPad seemed to go into mothballs a while back, so I (Disclosure alert: Yes, I made & sell this) made [MarkUpDown](http://markupdown.com), which isn't too shabby at $15. Should be GitHub Markdown friendly, and if it isn't, let me know how it isn't & I'll get it fixed.

Answer (score 44):

See [Python-Markdown-Editor](https://github.com/ncornette/Python-Markdown-Editor)

It is based on :

- Python-Markdown
- Pygments (code block syntax highlighting)
- CodeMirror (javascript code editor)
- Bottle

Install with pip :

```
$ pip install markdown-editor
```

It features when-you-type preview, code highlight, fenced code blocks, github style

it can be used by commandline :

```
$ markdown_edit 

$ markdown_edit README.md

$ markdown_edit -f readme.html README.md
```

[image]

I created this to build a tool for sending code reviews, it is easily extensible, by importing it as a module you can add custom actions.

Comment: Hello, this seems to be an great app, however I can not open two .md files at same time, since most of the time I just want it to be an viewer rather than editor. Will you extends this with such syntax as http://localhost:8000/<path/to/file.md> to make it able to view multiple .md files?

Comment: You can edit multiple files with `-p <port>` option

Comment: gives a Traceback error for me

Comment: Works, but you need to check the latest issues w.r.t version of Python-Markdown is needed. e.g. this report "Installing with pip the installation goes fine, but when launching the editor from command line it throws the following error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymdownx.extrarawhtml'

Uninstalling pymdown-extensions and reinstalling a previous version e.g. pymdown-extensions==7.0 solved the issue for me. This happens because the requirement for installation is pymdown-extensions>=2.0 but can quickly be fixed by specifying exact version."

Answer (score 29):

I just installed https://github.com/ypocat/gfms. It does a very good job rendering github flavored markdown. It detects changes in your markdown, so you just put your browser and editor side-by-side. It is Node.js, so it should work fine on any platform.

If you have Node.js is installed, the installation is simple:

1. `sudo npm install -g gfms`
2. `gfms --port 9999` (in your project directory)
3. `http://localhost:9999/` (open with any browser)

Comment: Unfortunately, ``gfms`` doesn't render line breaks the way that GFM does--it doesn't insert a <br> when there's a single line break inside of a paragraph, as GFM does. But for "pure" Markdown rendering, it's fine.

Comment: There is an updated version of **gfms** ([github.com/pawel-wiejacha/gfms](https://github.com/pawel-wiejacha/gfms)) that uses better GFM Markdown backend (Marked) and inserts line breaks correctly. It also has improved directory listings and PDF export feature.

Comment: I tried this because it sounded promising. Had to install node.js (expected) but also python. I gave up when it wanted a complete C++ developer toolchain. So depending on your platform it might be easy but if you are on Windows don't even try this suggestion.

Comment: Pretty much nothing written in NodeJS works on Windows.  When a "install this software" guide starts with "npm install", I've learned the hard way to just walk away.  NodeJS is not as cross-platform as developers would like people to believe.  Golang and Python are similarly bad but not as bad as Node.  The only scripting language that I know of that is truly cross-platform and works everywhere with minimal effort and doesn't require hundreds of MB of junk to be installed is PHP.  The PHP CLI is a hidden gem - it's better as a command-line scripting language than anything else out there.

Answer (score 28):

I found a way to view it in PHP. After doing some more snooping I found 2 solutions for offline and online viewing of .md files:

- **Offline:** https://github.com/WolfieZero/Markdown-Viewer-PHP
- **Online:** http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/dingus

I recommend the offline version so you can do your editing even while you're doing your business on the throne. :)

Comment: There are plenty of desktop apps for viewing `.md` files as well.

Comment: I didn't know that. What are they?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=markdown%20editor turns up http://markdownpad.com/ pretty immediately

Comment: @enchance, Why PHP? A javascript version would be better.

Answer (score 23):

[pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) is a nice Text-To-Text conversion tool that solves the problem of offline visualization of your Markdown. Just issue:

```
pandoc -f markdown -t html README.md > README.html
```

Answer (score 23):

There are people who does not use Google Chrome. There is a Firefox add-on called [Markdown Viewer](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/markdown-viewer-chrome/?src=search) which is able to read Markdown files offline.

Answer (score 20):

have you tried [ReText](https://github.com/retext-project/retext)? It is a nice desktop Markdown editor

Comment: so many dependencies. but seems nice enough!

Comment: Some information about how to install reText on Mac OS X can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/retext/wiki/Home/)

Comment: You may need to install some dependencies manually for it: sudo apt-get install python3-docutils python3-markdown

Comment: Everything gets set up automatically in Ubuntu 15.04, both dependencies and the mime type association.

Comment: Your link now gives a 404, sourceforge may have moved the project. I got to it via google, but here's the link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/retext/

Comment: the new link gives an error as well @NuclearPeon

Comment: @Moytaba Looks like its moved to github: https://github.com/retext-project/retext

Answer (score 14):

I found [MarkView Google Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markview/iaddkimmopgchbbnmfmdcophmlnghkim) pretty useful, actually it's working like a charm:

> MarkView is a Chrome extention for editing and viewing markdown file with an outline view, support multiple table format styles, code block syntax highlight and Github Flavored Markdown.
>
> Features:
>
> 1. Editing and Viewing markdown file in web page style.
> 2. Auto reload local file when file is changed  (**Post-installation:
>      select "Allow access to file URLs" option in chrome://extensions/**)
> 3. Show outline beside the content in scrollable way
> 4. Have buttons for GoTop, ViewSource and GoBottom
> 5. Support Github Flavored Markdown table styles and code highlight.
> 6. Highlight the code area for programming languages(eg. ```ruby)
> 7. Support web pages printing with decent outlook(Chrome->File->Print...)
> 8. Responsive: when the window size small than 940px, outline section will 
>      automatically hidden; resize bigger than 940px, outline section will display.
> 9. MarkView will view all markdown files except those under raw.github.com 
>      because that subdomain only displays the source.

More features have been added to MarkView:

1. WYSIWYG markdown editor
2. Themes and Code Styling Selection
3. Support Footnotes<sup>1</sup> *↩*
4. Instant Slides Presentation
5. Document Custom Styling

   - Add Theme CSS and Select
   - Add Code Style and Select
   - Write CSS, Save and Run

Answer (score 13):

I like the vertical splitter in [Downmarker](http://mindinthewater.blogspot.com.au/2011/05/downmarker-markdown-editorviewer.html), you can see the changes as you write!

Answer (score 11):

You can use [texts](http://www.texts.io/) as a md viewer and md editor, its lightweight and neat.
[image]

Comment: Looks good, but the installer is 13mb which makes me wonder what all it's installing.

Comment: Not free: http://www.texts.io/purchase/

Comment: Also not available for Linux.

Comment: I found this to render many md files quite poorly.

Comment: On the mac, it requires pre-installing some external tool "fandoc", which I don't know or trust, especially that it lies somewhere in my OS. The wrapper itself (Texts) weighs about 4MB which is far too big for an .md renderer, even without that external tool... well, not so impressive app.

Comment: Doesn't render images from git markdown. Forces you to install pandoc.

Comment: I tried it. It tries to be WYSIWYG but it changes what I'm writing as I write and it feels awkward - I don't feel in control. I've worked with other Markdown tools I was more comfortable with.
Also, as others have noted, it's not clear whether it's a trial or paid product. The Terms and Conditions sounded like a commercial product.

Answer (score 11):

[Geany](http://www.geany.org/) has a [plugin for markdown](http://plugins.geany.org/markdown.html) which does a fair job, giving you also a Markdown preview in the sidebar. It also runs on Linux, Mac OS X and Windows.

To use it, install geany, then install the package geany-plugin-markdown and select it from the plugin manager.

Answer (score 9):

I just coded up an offline markdown viewer using the node.js file watcher and socket.io, so you point your browser at localhost and run `./markdownviewer /path/to/README.md` and it streams it to the browser using websockets.

- markdownviewer https://github.com/Hainish/markdownviewer/

Answer (score 9):

There is also [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/). It will work both online and offline (it uses your browser local storage).

You can also connect it with Dropbox or Google Drive to see files hosted on the cloud.

Comment: Browser storage is very limited. Very very limited.

Answer (score 8):

If you're a vim person, you can try the [vim-preview](https://github.com/greyblake/vim-preview) plugin. Simply install it into your `~/.vim` directory with your method of choice. Then you can open a Markdown file with vim and use the command `:Preview` which will open a new window in your browser and display the end result.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, the plugin requires a builtin ruby interpreter and some gems. Too many dependencies for me...

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that - I had installed it a while ago so forgot to mention about the ruby gems (for future readers: the plugin's link I've included above describes how to tackle this if you're into that sort of ruby stuff).

Comment: Another vim plugin, this one using javascript: https://github.com/suan/vim-instant-markdown

Answer (score 7):

Consider [Strapdown](http://strapdownjs.com/).

Strapdown is Javascript-based solution that renders the markdown content in the browser, which makes it great for offline-viewing.
From their own description:

> Strapdown.js makes it embarrassingly simple to create elegant Markdown documents. No server-side compilation required.

So rename your `.md` markdown file to `.html`, and surround it with:

```
<xmp theme="united" style="display:none;">
# Markdown content here
…
</xmp>
<script src="http://strapdownjs.com/v/0.2/strapdown.js"></script>
```

and opening in any browser will show rendered HTML. Added bonus: you can easily change the theme.

Answer (score 6):

One of the simplest resources that works well on MacOSX is the Markdown Quick Look plugin found at [InkMark](http://inkmarkapp.com/markdown-quick-look-plugin-mac-os-x/). After installing this on OS X 10.9+, you simply select a markdown file in Finder and tap the space bar. I am not certain if the results are correlated 100% with Github but they are pretty good and make for a tiny unobtrusive offline viewer only solution. [Mashable](http://mashable.com/2013/06/24/markdown-tools/) also wrote an article on 78 different tools if you'd like other options.

[image: Makrdown-QuickLook-Preview]

Answer (score 6):

An easy solution for most situations: copy/paste the markdown into a viewer in the "cloud."  Here are two choices:

1. [Dillinger.io](http://dillinger.io/)
2. [Dingus](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/dingus)

Nothing to install! Cross platform! Cross browser! Always available!

Disadvantages: could be hassle for large files, standard cloud application security issues.

Comment: And, of course, You're sharing your pre-release docs with the whole wide world, before even being able to proof them...

Answer (score 5):

For MAC I use [Marked](http://markedapp.com/), for Windows I use [Muto-Mark](https://github.com/pseudomuto/muto-mark). Both support the GH stylesheet.

Comment: +1 : I am using MutoMark for windows: 1. It's very light (395KB) 2. Nice viewer 3. Search capability (Ctr + F) 4. Highlights all search results

Comment: sadly doesn't seems to support file association

Answer (score 4):

For OS X, [Mou](http://mouapp.com/) is very nice, and it comes with two GitHub CSS themes.

Comment: Nice but buggy. E.g. you remove the header marks ###, but the WYSIWYG part still shows it as header. And so on and on, I think I found some 3 or 4 bugs in 2 minutes of using it.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Haroopad](http://pad.haroopress.com/). This is a really nice #markdown editor. It is free and available for multiple platforms. I've tried it on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 3):

You can use extension called [Markdown Syntax Highlighting](https://github.com/wfwei/Notepad---Markdown-Highlighting) for Notepad++. It is available on Github

[image]

After installation, new option in the Language dropdown will be appeared
[image: After installation, new option in the Language dropdown will be appeared]

Comment: Exciting.  Can you add a link to Github?

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The goal is for the end-result to show, not the source.

Answer (score 2):

From now I use http://marxi.co/. Marxi.co has online and offline version.

Answer (score 2):

## Remarkable, certainly a great tool.

Note: **Not available for Mac**

#### Features:

- Live preview
- It's **free**.
- Extremely lightweight
- Export to HTML, PDF

Download: https://remarkableapp.github.io/

### Edit 2022

I use and love **Mark Text** now. (https://marktext.app)

Comment: Only works in Linux. The Windows version is in progress.

Comment: Not really "Cross" platform. Linux and Windows only - no Mac.

Comment: For what it's worth, I use Mark Text on Mac, and it's the closest thing I've found to a plain viewer.

Comment: Mark Text looks very promising and I expect it to be a better solution than the others mentioned so far. However, I didn't try it yet because the download is 149 MB (!). This is a little heavy for a simple editor. It's not that I am concerned about space consumption, but what ecosystem / underlying software stack would it install? If it's Java or something like that, I won't try it.

Answer (score 2):

I frequently want portable applications. For this, I found

http://cloose.github.io/CuteMarkEd/  (I have just tried it briefly, and it seems to work fine).

http://markdownpad.com/faq.html#portable

Comment: Seems quite buggy actually

Comment: I used 0.11.3 and it works nicely for me...

Answer (score 2):

[RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/) can handle markdown files and convert them into html and pdf. If you already have it, you can use RStudio (it is an IDE for R programming language). It is free and open source, and works on Windows, Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You may use **Scribefire** Next.

It's a **Mozilla Firefox** browser plugin. Just install the extension and fire up Firefox. Customize your toolbar and place the Scribefire shortcut to it. And since it's a browser plugin, you can use it in Mac, Linux and Windows.

When you want to write in Markdown mode, just click `Edit Code` from the Scribefire window.

Now to meet your purpose, go to `Edit Code` mode and copy all the texts and paste it to your `.md` file and upload.

There is no live preview feature for this, you have to toggle `Edit Code` and `Edit Visually` to preview your text.

I'm using it in my Linux Mint box:

[image]

[image]

### Update:

It's year 2014, need to add some other awesome tool here for other readers and researchers. Just recently used [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) + [Markdown Preview Extension](https://github.com/gruehle/MarkdownPreview).

Answer (score 1):

The popular Web Essentials plugin for Visual Studio offers a Markdown viewer and editor.  It also supports the Github language syntax for adding code snippets.

http://vswebessentials.com/features/markdown

Answer (score 0):

This php viewer come with responsive support and a numbers of option to customize.

- Codespire Dokumen: http://www.binpress.com/app/codespire-dokumen-responsive-markdown-viewer/2112

Answer (score 0):

You may use Firefox Markdown Viewer plugin that is so easy to install and use.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/download) ebook viewer does an OK job of parsing markdown files and displaying them.

Once calibre is installed, just `ebook-viewer myfile.md`.